# Laravel: How to respond with custom 404 error depending on route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, http-status-code-404, laravel-routing

I'm using [Laravel4](http://laravel.com) framework and I came across this problem.

I want to display a custom 404 error depending on requested url.

For example:

```
Route::get('site/{something}', function($something){
    return View::make('site/error/404');
});
```

and

```
Route::get('admin/{something}', function($something){
    return View::make('admin/error/404');
});
```

The value of `'$something'` is not important.

Shown example only works with one segment, i.e. `'site/foo'` or `'admin/foo'`.
If someone request `'site/foo/bar'` or `'admin/foo/bar'` laravel will throw default 404 error.

```
App::missing(function($exception){
    return '404: Page Not Found';
});
```

I tried to find something in Laravel4 documentation but nothing is just right for me.
Please help :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In `app/start/global.php`

```
App::missing(function($exception) 
{
    if (Request::is('admin/*'))
    {
        return Response::view('admin.missing',array(),404);
    }
    else if (Request::is('site/*'))
    {
        return Response::view('site.missing',array(),404);
    }
    else
    {
         return Response::view('default.missing',array(),404);
    }
});
```

In your view, you can find `$something` with `{{ Request::path(); }}` or `{{ Request::segment(); }}`

Comment: There a nice discussion of this at: http://blog.danharper.me/blog/2013/01/01/exceptions-in-laravel-4/

Comment: Anyone have an updated version of this for Laravel 5.5...?