# I want to redirect Laravel version 5.2 default 404 page to my template page of 404, from where and what to change

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel version 5.2 and don't know how to redirect Laravel default page to my template 404 page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: How to respond with custom 404 error depending on route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972276/laravel-how-to-respond-with-custom-404-error-depending-on-route)

Comment: laravel version is different and these methods are not present in laravel 5.2 as suggested in this link, i tried this but failed, plz give any other link for solution @Carpetsmoker

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use `abort(404);`

> Some exceptions describe HTTP error codes from the server. For
>   example, this may be a "page not found" error (404), an "unauthorized
>   error" (401) or even a developer generated 500 error. In order to
>   generate such a response from anywhere in your application, use the
>   following:
>
> ```
> abort(404);
> ```

If you invoke `abort(404);` anywhere in your route or controller it will throw `HTTPNotFoundException` which looks for a blade template to display in `resources/views/errors/` directory with the filename same as the error code.

Example:

in your `app/Http/routes.php`

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
   return abort(404);
});
```

in your `resources/views/errors/` directory create **404**.blade.php, notice the name of the file corresponds with the abort(**404**);

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#http-exceptions

Comment: plz guide in which file i add "abort(404)" function?

Comment: @AbidAli updated my answer with additional info and example

Comment: Bundle of thanks @TheHamsterOfGod , yes its working ok. when i put 404.blade.php view on your suggested place. Execellent Job

Answer (score 3):

Modify app/Exceptions/Handler.php and add some lines as below:-

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
  if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) 
  {
    return redirect('/');
  } 
 return parent::render($request, $e); }
```

Use your route name in place of / where you want to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view and set this code in **app/Exceptions/Handler.php** :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
.
.
.
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        return response()->view('missing', [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the /resources/views/errors directory there is a 404 page

edit this page and you can make it look like you want